# How to compute large matrix-vector multiplication by splitting data and using multithreading multiple GPU efficiently?

Tags: multithreading, cuda, gpu

I am new to GPU computation. I want to compute the result of `XX^TY` where X is a large matrix (N by P) and Y is a vector (N by 1). Now I want to split the matrix X into several blocks and first compute the local result for each device. Finally, I use all-ring reduce to get the sum result. My demo code is as the following

```
typedef unsigned long long uint64;

struct DevicePro {
    // pointer of device memory
    float* deviceData;
    float* deviceVec;
    float* deviceRes;

    // cuda context
    cudaStream_t stream;

    int gpuID;
    uint64 blockSize; // block size of each matrix-vec computation
    uint64 dataSplitIndex; // data start index for each device
    uint64 resultLength;
}


// allocate memory on each device
    for (int i = 0; i < numDevice; ++i) {
        int currDevice = deviceProList[i];
        cudaSetDevice(currDevice.gpuID);

        gpuErrchk(cudaStreamCreate(&currDevice.stream));
        gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(reinterpret_cast<void **>(&currDevice.deviceData), rows * currDevice.blockSize * sizeof(float)));
        gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(reinterpret_cast<void **>(&currDevice.deviceVec), rows * sizeof(float)));
        gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(reinterpret_cast<void **>(&currDevice.deviceRes), rows * sizeof(float)));
    }

    // start computation
    // first we need to know how many blocks we have
    uint64 numBlock = static_cast<uint64>(dataSplitSize / deviceProList[0].blockSize) + 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < numDevice; ++i) {
        for (uint64 block = 0; block < numBlock; ++block) {
            DevicePro currDevice = deviceProList[i];
            //transfer data and launch kernel
        }
    }


    // free cuda memory
    for (int i = 0; i < numDevice; ++i) {
        int currDevice = deviceProList[i];
        cudaSetDevice(currDevice.gpuID);

        gpuErrchk(cudaFree(currDevice.deviceData));
        gpuErrchk(cudaFree(currDevice.deviceRes));
        gpuErrchk(cudaFree(currDevice.deviceVec));
    }
```

I cannot put the whole data into GPU memory even I split them. That is why I need this loop `for (uint64 block = 0; block < numBlock; ++block)`. Here I assume that the number of blocks is same for all device. My question is as the following

1. Can I use multithread to start data transfer and kernel computation on each device? Otherwise, the device 2 has to wait until device 1 finished all its invocation.

Comment: I am not convinced your last comment is correct -- if you pin the memory, use streams and the asynchronous versions of all the APIs and rewrite the loop to be breath first and not depth first, you could do this with one thread and still have overlap on all devices

Comment: @talonmies What if the block number is not same for each device?

Comment: You said in your question you assume the number of blocks is the same. My remark is based on that. If it is't the same breadth first can still work. Imagine pre-calculating the work split and pushing it onto a work stack for each device. Instead of fixed trip loops, have a stack pop. If one device reach empty before another, the empty device is just skipped. When you reach one device, you are back to the depth first operation above

Comment: @talonmies Could you please show me a demo towards that? What's more, if I use the breadth first way to do this, as for the last device, it has to wait until all former asynchronous API finished. Is that right?

Comment: Sorry, no. I not writing you are framework prototype to explain something which I think I have adequately described in my comments above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I use multithread to start data transfer and kernel computation on each device?

Yes. The runtime API is thread safe and this could certainly be done with a host thread per GPU if correctly designed (possibly even OpenMP or other host multi-threading compiler driven abstraction).

However, as discussed in comments, if you use streams and asynchronous APIs, it should be perfectly possible to write a breadth first version which would run concurrently on multiple devices from a single controlling host thread.